# Collocating cache entries needed for replicated caches with PRIMARY_SYNC & 'CacheConfiguration#readFromBackup' flag to false?

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497095/explicit-setting-of-write-synchronization-mode-full-sync-needed-for-replicated-c) that replicated caches can be set to use 'PRIMARY_SYNC' write synchronization mode (the default) and 'CacheConfiguration#readFromBackup' flag can be set to false (true by default) to make Ignite send the request to primary node and get the value from there.

Does that mean that one also needs to correspondingly take care of Collocating cache entries aswell to ensure performance?

Comment: Can you describe the use case? What is collocated with what?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko If i have lets say two replicated caches Department & Employee with the default 'PRIMARY_SYNC' sync mode with readFromBackup flag set to false to make Ignite send requests to primary node & get value from there then would it help to have Employee collocated with Department so the request need not be sent to 2 different nodes?. Sorry if i am not clear..this was a side question/confusion that came out of the answer to my earlier this question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497095/explicit-setting-of-write-synchronization-mode-full-sync-needed-for-replicated-c)

Comment: What is "the request"? Request for what? What is the operation you're executing?

Comment: Request for data....a query joining department & employee for one or more departments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collocation is not needed when query with join is executed against replicated caches. Also the query is always distributed, so `readFromBackup` doesn't have any affect in this case. Write synchronization mode (`PRIMARY_SYNC`/`FULL_SYNC`) affects only writes.